# Android, I can't refresh my fragment data?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I was building a simple Quiz App which uses two fragments, one for multiple choice questions and one for free answer questions (type your own answer).

Now in order to display the questions correctly I need to use positions (1 through 5) to display the correct questions at the correct time.

I got the .replace working to replace my fragment but it is replacing the same fragments over and over (which is what i wanted). But now i can't get the fragment to update the questions correctly because it's not updating the position.

If i can get this working on one of the fragments I will also be able to get it working on the other fragment (I hope).

I need to be able to do this back and forth.

McQuestionFragment.java

```
public class McQuestionFragment extends Fragment {
    private int position;

    //Refresh method??? Im clueless how to implement this. Needs to update the position
    private void updatePosition(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mcquestion, container, false);

        //TODO:: get the checkboxes and set possible answers based on question you are current at (using the position)
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cb.setText(String.valueOf(this.position));

        return view;

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    private McQuestionFragment mcFragment;
    private QuestionFragment questionFragment;

    private int shownId;
    private int progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        questionFragment = new QuestionFragment();
        mcFragment = new McQuestionFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, questionFragment).commit();

        //Go forward
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progress = progress + 1;
                if (shownId == 1) {
                    shownId = 2;
                    setProgressBar();
                    mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mcFragment).commit();
                } else if (shownId == 2) {
                    shownId = 1;
                    setProgressBar();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, questionFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        });

        //Go back
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(shownId == 2){
                    shownId = 1;
                    progress = progress -1;
                    setProgressBar();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, questionFragment).commit();
                }else if(shownId == 1){
                    shownId = 2;
                    progress = progress -1;
                    setProgressBar();
                    mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mcFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

I have tried to use .attach and .detach but I couldn't get it to work myself. Any help would be appreciated.

~Thank you in advance~

EDIT 1::
Using Radu's answer i tried to do the following thing but it is giving me a nullpointerexception.

```
public class McQuestionFragment extends Fragment {
    private int position;
    private CheckBox cb;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mcquestion, container, false);

        //TODO:: get the checkboxes and set possible answers based on question you are current at (using the position)
        this.cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cb.setText(String.valueOf(this.position));

        return view;

    }   

    //Refresh method??? 
    public void updatePosition(int position){
        this.position = position;

        //NULLPOINTER
        cb.setText(String.valueOf(this.position));
    }
}
```

EDIT 2::
Edited the MainActivity.java but it still gives me a nullpointer exception. Updated code:

```
if (shownId == 1) {
                shownId = 2;
                setProgressBar();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mcFragment).commit();
                mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);
            } else if (shownId == 2) {
                shownId = 1;
                setProgressBar();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, questionFragment).commit();
            }
```

EDIT 3::
Still getting the nullpointer even with .attach and .detach

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progress = progress + 1;
                if (shownId == 1) {
                    shownId = 2;
                    setProgressBar();
                    mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);
                    fm.beginTransaction().detach(questionFragment).attach(mcFragment).replace(R.id.container, mcFragment).commit();
                } else if (shownId == 2) {
                    shownId = 1;
                    setProgressBar();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, questionFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You must chang lines like this: 
mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mcFragment).commit();
mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Comment: do you still get NullPointer exception error or something else ?

Comment: Yes I am still getting the same NullPointer exception and I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a good night sleep i've figured out that i could just use .show() and .hide() to show and hide fragments when they are already added.

Updated button code:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress = progress + 1;
            if (shownId == 1) {
                shownId = 2;
                setProgressBar();
                if(!mcFragment.isAdded()) {
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mcFragment).hide(questionFragment).commit();
                }else {
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(questionFragment).show(mcFragment).commit();
                    mcFragment.updatePosition(progress);
                }
            } else if (shownId == 2) {
                shownId = 1;
                setProgressBar();
                if(!questionFragment.isAdded()) {
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(mcFragment).add(R.id.container, questionFragment).commit();
                }else{
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(mcFragment).show(questionFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    CheckBox cb;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mcquestion, container, false);

        //TODO:: get the checkboxes and set possible answers based on question you are current at (using the position)
        cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cb.setText(String.valueOf(this.position));

        return view;

    }

private void updatePosition(int position){
            this.position = position;
            cb.setText(String.valueOf(this.position));
        }
```

This should do exatcly what your `onCreateView()` method does when you first create the `Fragment`, but using new `position` value.

Comment: Do i call it in MainActivity like: mcFragment.updatePosition(progress) before replacing the fragment?

Comment: You do not even need to replace the fragment, since you are updating its content by this call

Comment: I do need to replace it because i need to replace the QuestionFragment

Comment: You should call it after replacing the fragment, because that is when your Views are getting inflated (created)

Comment: I am getting a nullpointer on cb.setText(). See updated post at the edit 1

Comment: You should then use the  modified code above, in which you store a reference to the CheckBox.

Comment: Like @MustafaOlkun suggested in his comment you need to first add the Fragment and then call updatePosition. Have you done that?

Comment: Your getting that error because you are using .replace which causes a fragment to be destroyed (calls the onPause and sometimes onDestroy) so your view for that fragment is null. To fix recreate the fragment each time or alternatively use .attach and .detach.

Comment: Austi01101110, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Move your line below to onStart() from onCreateView() and try again.

```
cb.setText(String.valueOf(this.position));
```

Please inform me when you try.